# Find Common Region in two CSV File in PYTHON

Tags: python, csv

I have two CSV files with 10 columns each where the first column is called the "Primary Key".

I need to use Python to find the common region between the two CSV files. For example, I should be able to detect that rows 27-45 in CSV1 is equal to rows 125-145 in CSV2 and so on.

I am only comparing the Primary Key (Column One). The rest of the data is not considered for comparison. I need to extract these common regions in two separate CSV files (one for CSV1 and one for CSV2).

I have already parsed and stored the rows of the two CSV files in two 'list of lists',  `lstCAN_LOG_TABLE` and `lstSHADOW_LOG_TABLE`, so the problem reduces down to comparing these two list of lists.

I am currently assuming is that if there are 10 subsequent matches (`MAX_COMMON_THRESHOLD`), I have reached the beginning of a common region. I must not log single rows (comparing to true) because there would be regions equal (As per primary key) and those regions I need to identify.

```
for index in range(len(lstCAN_LOG_TABLE)):
    for l_index in range(len(lstSHADOW_LOG_TABLE)):
        if(lstSHADOW_LOG_TABLE[l_index][1] == lstCAN_LOG_TABLE[index][1]):  #Consider for comparison only CAN IDs
            index_can_log = index                                           #Position where CAN Log is to be compared
            index_shadow_log = l_index                                      #Position from where CAN Shadow Log is to be considered
            start = index_shadow_log
            if((index_shadow_log + MAX_COMMON_THRESHOLD) <= (input_file_two_row_count-1)):
                end = index_shadow_log + MAX_COMMON_THRESHOLD
            else:
                end = (index_shadow_log) + ((input_file_two_row_count-1) - (index_shadow_log))
            can_index = index
            bPreScreened = 1
            for num in range(start,end):
                if(lstSHADOW_LOG_TABLE[num][1] == lstCAN_LOG_TABLE[can_index][1]):
                    if((can_index + 1) < (input_file_one_row_count-1)):
                        can_index = can_index + 1                           
                    else:
                        break   
                else:
                    bPreScreened = 0
                    print("No Match")
                    break
            #we might have found start of common region         
            if(bPreScreened == 1):      
                print("Start={0} End={1} can_index={2}".format(start,end,can_index))
                for number in range(start,end):
                    if(lstSHADOW_LOG_TABLE[number][1] == lstCAN_LOG_TABLE[index][1]):                           
                        writer_two.writerow(lstSHADOW_LOG_TABLE[number][0])
                        writer_one.writerow(lstCAN_LOG_TABLE[index][0])
                        if((index + 1) < (input_file_one_row_count-1)):
                            index = index + 1                           
                        else:
                            dump_file.close()   
                            print("\nCommon Region in Two CSVs identifed and recorded\n")                           
                            return
dump_file.close()   
print("\nCommon Region in Two CSVs identifed and recorded\n")
```

I am getting strange output. Even the first CSV file has only 1880 Rows but in the common region CSV for the first CSV I am getting many more entries. I am not getting desired output.

**EDITED FROM HERE**

**CSV1:**

```
216 0.000238225 F4  41  C0  FB  28  0   0   0   MS CAN
109 0.0002256   15  8B  31  0   8   43  58  0   HS CAN
216 0.000238025 FB  47  C6  1   28  0   0   0   MS CAN
340 0.000240175 0A  18  0   C2  0   0   6F  FF  MS CAN
216 0.000240225 24  70  EF  28  28  0   0   0   MS CAN
216 0.000236225 2B  77  F7  2F  28  0   0   0   MS CAN
216 0.0002278   31  7D  FD  35  28  0   0   0   MS CAN
```

**CSV2:**

```
216 0.0002361   0F  5C  DB  14  28  0   0   0   MS CAN
216 0.000236225 16  63  E2  1B  28  0   0   0   MS CAN
109 0.0001412   16  A3  31  0   8   63  58  0   HS CAN
216 0.000234075 1C  6A  E9  22  28  0   0   0   MS CAN
40A 0.000259925 C1  1   46  54  30  44  47  36  HS CAN
4A  0.000565975 2   0   0   0   0   0   0   C0  MS CAN
340 0.000240175 0A  18  0   C2  0   0   6F  FF  MS CAN
216 0.000240225 24  70  EF  28  28  0   0   0   MS CAN
216 0.000236225 2B  77  F7  2F  28  0   0   0   MS CAN
216 0.0002278   31  7D  FD  35  28  0   0   0   MS CAN
```

**EXPECTED OUTPUT CSV1:**

```
340 0.000240175 0A  18  0   C2  0   0   6F  FF  MS CAN
216 0.000240225 24  70  EF  28  28  0   0   0   MS CAN
216 0.000236225 2B  77  F7  2F  28  0   0   0   MS CAN
216 0.0002278   31  7D  FD  35  28  0   0   0   MS CAN
```

**EXPECTED OUTPUT CSV2:**

```
340 0.000240175 0A  18  0   C2  0   0   6F  FF  MS CAN
216 0.000240225 24  70  EF  28  28  0   0   0   MS CAN
216 0.000236225 2B  77  F7  2F  28  0   0   0   MS CAN
216 0.0002278   31  7D  FD  35  28  0   0   0   MS CAN
```

**OBSERVED OUTPUT CSV1**

```
340 0.000240175 0A  18  0   C2  0   0   6F  FF  MS CAN
216 0.000240225 24  70  EF  28  28  0   0   0   MS CAN
216 0.000236225 2B  77  F7  2F  28  0   0   0   MS CAN
216 0.0002278   31  7D  FD  35  28  0   0   0   MS CAN
```

And many thousands of redundant row data

**EDITED - SOLVED AS PER ADVICE (CHANGED FOR TO WHILE):**

**LEARNING:** *In Python FOR Loop Index cannot be changed at RunTime*

```
dump_file=open("MATCH_PATTERN.txt",'w+')
print("Number of Entries CAN LOG={0}".format(len(lstCAN_LOG_TABLE)))
print("Number of Entries SHADOW LOG={0}".format(len(lstSHADOW_LOG_TABLE)))  
index = 0   
while(index < (input_file_one_row_count - 1)):
    l_index = 0
    while(l_index < (input_file_two_row_count - 1)):
        if(lstSHADOW_LOG_TABLE[l_index][1] == lstCAN_LOG_TABLE[index][1]):  #Consider for comparison only CAN IDs
            index_can_log = index                                           #Position where CAN Log is to be compared
            index_shadow_log = l_index                                      #Position from where CAN Shadow Log is to be considered
            start = index_shadow_log
            can_index = index
            if((index_shadow_log + MAX_COMMON_THRESHOLD) <= (input_file_two_row_count-1)):
                end = index_shadow_log + MAX_COMMON_THRESHOLD
            else:
                end = (index_shadow_log) + ((input_file_two_row_count-1) - (index_shadow_log))              
            bPreScreened = 1
            for num in range(start,end):
                if(lstSHADOW_LOG_TABLE[num][1] == lstCAN_LOG_TABLE[can_index][1]):                      
                    if((can_index + 1) < (input_file_one_row_count-1)):
                        can_index = can_index + 1                           
                    else:
                        break   
                else:
                    bPreScreened = 0
                    break
            #we might have found start of common region         
            if(bPreScreened == 1):      
                print("Shadow Start={0} Shadow End={1} CAN INDEX={2}".format(start,end,index))
                for number in range(start,end):
                    if(lstSHADOW_LOG_TABLE[number][1] == lstCAN_LOG_TABLE[index][1]):                           
                        writer_two.writerow(lstSHADOW_LOG_TABLE[number][0])
                        writer_one.writerow(lstCAN_LOG_TABLE[index][0])
                        if((index + 1) < (input_file_one_row_count-1)):
                            index = index + 1
                        if((l_index + 1) < (input_file_two_row_count-1)):
                            l_index = l_index + 1                               
                        else:
                            dump_file.close()   
                            print("\nCommon Region in Two CSVs identifed and recorded\n")                           
                            return
            else:
                l_index = l_index + 1
        else:
            l_index = l_index + 1
    index = index + 1   
dump_file.close()   
print("\nCommon Region in Two CSVs identifed and recorded\n")
```

Comment: You basically want to join your files on the 1st column? Or you just want the position ? Can you provide anyway minimalist example output and expected output ?

Comment: The 2 CSV files shall have some common regions. Few rows in first CSV files matches with equal number of rows in 2nd CSV file (When I say rows being equal,I mean only the primary key.The rest of the column values might differ). However the starting position of matching rows in second CSV file might not correspond to starting position of matching rows in first CSV file. 

The algorithm above I am dumping the common rows in two separate CSVs but I am getting more entries (The first CSV file has 1000 rows but after running the algorithm I am getting the common region but I am getting 22000 rows).

Comment: for index in range(len(lstCAN_LOG_TABLE)):
   if((index + 1) < (input_file_one_row_count-1)):
      index = index + 1

For some reason the index drops. I feel the index should always go up. I don't know why the index drops to some old value

Comment: Please edit your question with input and expected output.

Comment: Original post edited.

Comment: Are you interested an all common regions longer than a certain length or in the single longest common region? If you want the longest common region check out the [longest common substring problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`index` is the iterator in your `for` loop. Should you changed it inside the loop, it will be reassigned after each iteration.

Say, when `index = 5` in your `for` loop, and `index += 1` was execute 3 times. Now `index = 8`. But after this iteration ends, when your code go back to `for`, index will be assigned to `index x = 6`.

Try following example:

```
for index in range(0,5):
    print 'iterator:', index
    index = index + 2
    print 'index:', index
```

The output will be:

```
iterator: 0
index: 2
iterator: 1
index: 3
iterator: 2
index: 4
iterator: 3
index: 5
iterator: 4
index: 6
```

To fix this issue, you might want to change your `for` loop to `while` loop

**EDIT:**
If I didn't understand wrong, you were trying to find 'same' columns in two files and store them.
If this is the case, actually your work can be done easily by using following code:

```
import csv # import csv module to read csv files

file1 = 'csv1.csv' # input file 1
file2 = 'csv2.csv' # input file 2
outfile = 'csv3.csv' # only have one output file since two output files will be the same

read1 = csv.reader(open(file1, 'r')) # read input file 1
write = csv.writer(open(outfile, 'w')) # write to output file

# for each row in input file 1, compare it with each row in input file 2
# if they are the same, write that row into output file
for row1 in read1:
    read2 = csv.reader(open(file2, 'r'))
    for row2 in read2:
        if row1 == row2:
            write.writerow(row1)

read1.close()
write.close()
```

Comment: Thanks JoYSwordless. I shall make the changes accordingly.

Comment: @AbhishekDhar Hi there, I'm not sure if I understood your question correctly but if I didn't misunderstand, there should be an easy way to solve your problem, see updated answer. At least it works for your sample input/output in your post.

Comment: actually the problem is slightly more convoluted than that. There are two CSV files with same number of columns and same column names (So two CSV files with same attributes). CAN ID is the primary key (One of the attribute) that is the only common factor between two CSV files. It is quite possible that entire CSV1 is contained within CSV2 (All rows of CSV1 with CAN ID from 'x' to 'y' contained within CSV2 'x' to 'y' but the other attributes of those common rows with same CAN IDs might be different) OR a subset of rows in CSV1 might be contained within CSV2 (Same sequence of CAN ID)

Comment: The idea is to identify that common region between the 2 CSV files (Rows which has perfect match for CAN ID and in the exact same sequence) & hence log in the corresponding rows in two different CSV files so that difference in other attributes can be identified and other statistics can be generated (Like occurrence count of one particular CAN ID, Standard Deviation, Variance etc).

So various UseCases are possible (All rows of CSV1 contained within CSV2,a subset of rows of CSV1 contained within CSV2)But when I say same row,I only mean same CAN ID & in same sequence(Other attributes may vary).

Comment: I followed your advice and changed the FOR to WHILE and ALGO works fine now. Thanks a lot for the valuable piece of advice.