# How To iterate throw two csv file in Python

Tags: python, csv

I have two data tables related to journals (title, issn ...) and basically I want to know if journal of table1 is present in table2. For comparing I only use a digital identifier, named **issn**

My basic problem is that I dont manage to iterate throw all *tab1*, it stops after the end of *tab2*.

```py
import csv

tab1 = open("tab1.csv", 'r', encoding='utf8')
readtab1 = csv.DictReader(tab1)

tab2 = open("tab2.csv", 'r', encoding='utf8')
readtab2 = csv.DictReader(tab2)

linenb1 = 0
for row1 in readtab1:
    issn1 = row1['ISSN'].strip()
    linenb1 +=1

    linenb2 = 0 
    for row2 in readtab2 : 
        issn2 = row2['ISSN'].strip()
        if len(issn2) < 2 : continue
        linenb2+=1

        print(linenb1, linenb2, issn1,issn2)
```

consol

```
1 1 2552-8831 0001-253X
1 2 2552-8831 0002-2667
[Finished in 0.2s]
```

tab1

```
Nom du titre,ISSN,Format,nom editeur
Revue Droit & Litterature,2552-8831,Papier,LGDJ MONTCHRESTIEN
Memoires en Jeu,2497-2711,Papier,EDITIONS KIME
Le Monde,2262-4694,Online,LE MONDE
Journal des Energies Renouvelables,2491-8687,Papier + e-mail,OBSERVER
```

tab2

```
ISSN,TITLE,TARGET_PUBLIC_NAME,TARGET_SERVICE,THRESHOLD_ACTIVE,THRESHOLD_GLOBAL,PUBLISHER,LOCAL_THRESHOLD
0001-253X,Aslib proceedings,French National Licences Emerald,getFullTxt,"$obj->parsedDate('>=',1949,1,1) && $obj->parsedDate('<=',2010,65,6)","$obj->parsedDate('>=',1949,1,1) && $obj->parsedDate('<=',2010,65,6)",Emerald Group Publishing Ltd.,
0002-2667,Aircraft Engineering,French National Licences Emerald,getFullTxt,"$obj->parsedDate('>=',1929,1,1) && $obj->parsedDate('<=',1986,58,3)","$obj->parsedDate('>=',1929,1,1) && $obj->parsedDate('<=',1986,58,3)",Emerald Group Pub.,
```

I dont get because nested `for` loop works :

```py
for i in range(0,5):
    for j in range(1,10):
        print(i,j)
```

Comment: A DictReader needs fieldnames. Please specify the fieldnames.

Comment: thank you, I added them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second loop was satying at the end, the solution is to add `tab2.seek(0)`
I found the solution here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/26526224/3334635

What is strange for me is that it works with number, but not with csv reader

```py
import csv

tab1 = open("tab1.csv", 'r', encoding='utf8', newline='')
readtab1 = csv.DictReader(tab1)

tab2 = open("tab2.csv", 'r', encoding='utf8', newline='')
readtab2 = csv.DictReader(tab2)

linenb1 = 0
for row1 in readtab1:
    issn1 = row1['ISSN'].strip()
    linenb1 +=1

    linenb2 = 0 
    for row2 in readtab2 : 
        issn2 = row2['ISSN'].strip()
        if len(issn2) < 2 : continue
        linenb2+=1

        print(linenb1, linenb2, issn1,issn2)    

    tab2.seek(0)
    next(readtab2)  # skip header
```

```
1 1 2552-8831 0001-253X
1 2 2552-8831 0002-2667
2 1 2497-2711 0001-253X
2 2 2497-2711 0002-2667
3 1 2262-4694 0001-253X
3 2 2262-4694 0002-2667
4 1 2491-8687 0001-253X
4 2 2491-8687 0002-2667
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try setting the `fieldnames` and `delimiter` values of the `DictReader`s. Because they respectively default to the first row's values and a comma, whereas the data does not have a header row and it's separated by spaces.

```
fieldnames = "Nom du titre,ISSN,Format,Nom de l'éditeur,Nom de l'abonné".split(',')
abt = open("tab1.csv", 'r', encoding='utf8')
readTab1= csv.DictReader(abt, fieldnames=fieldnames, delimiter=' ')

sfx = open("tab2.csv", 'r', encoding='utf8')
readTab2 = csv.DictReader(sfx, fieldnames=fieldnames, delimiter=' ')

linenb = 0
for row1 in readTab1:
    issn1 = row1['ISSN'].strip()
    if len(issn1) < 2 : continue
    linenb +=1

    linenb2 = 0 
    for row2 in readTab2: 
        issn2 = row2['ISSN'].strip()
        if len(issn2) < 2 : continue
        linenb2+=1

        print(linenb,issn1,issn2)
```

Comment: tks @jab but the first row of my tables are _headers_, and the seperators is the _comma_ (I generate my CSV file). Therefore, I have the same behavior with your code proposal .  btw my tab2 has 44000 rows

Comment: Please update your question with better data sample and headers then as I cannot figure out the issue with the information given.

Comment: thank you, I have edit my question and added my data.